# Django - Variable coming from context processor not updated when deployed but works locally

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm deploying a Django website to a DigitalOcean Droplet, using Nginx and Gunicorn.

The idea is to every month **update the date depending on the current day**. Locally works perfectly but once deployed, the value doesn't update, in order to make it update I have to restart Gunicorn with the next command:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

**Do you know what is stopping the variables of being updated?**

The project has an App called "pages", which it has a **utils.py** in charge of calculating and prepare the date in two languages:

```
from babel.dates import format_date
import calendar
import datetime
import locale
import time


def cat_date():

    # get current date
    num_date = str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    current_month = int(time.strftime("%m"))
    current_year = int(time.strftime("%Y"))
    today = datetime.date.today()

    # get last day of current month
    last_day_current_month = calendar.monthrange(current_year, current_month)[1]
    date_last = today.replace(day=last_day_current_month)
    date_last_day_current_month_num = date_last.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    # get last week date
    date_prev_week = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    num_date_prev_week = date_prev_week.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    month_lw = int(date_prev_week.strftime("%m"))
    year_lw = int(date_prev_week.strftime("%Y"))

    # get last day of previous month
    last_day_previous_month = calendar.monthrange(year_lw, month_lw)[1]
    date_last_prev = date_prev_week.replace(day=last_day_previous_month)
    date_last_day_previous_month_num = date_last_prev.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    # use babel to get the long readable formated date
    catalan_text_date_current = format_date(date_last, format='long', locale='ca')
    catalan_text_date_previous = format_date(date_last_prev, format='long', locale='ca')

    # choose date to display depending on current date
    day_today = int(today.strftime("%d"))
    if day_today > 3:
        return date_last_day_current_month_num, catalan_text_date_current
    else:
        return date_last_day_previous_month_num, catalan_text_date_previous


def es_date():

    # get current date
    num_date = str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    current_month = int(time.strftime("%m"))
    current_year = int(time.strftime("%Y"))
    today = datetime.date.today()

    # get last day of current month
    last_day_current_month = calendar.monthrange(current_year, current_month)[1]
    date_last = today.replace(day=last_day_current_month)
    date_last_day_current_month_num = date_last.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    # get last week date
    date_prev_week = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    num_date_prev_week = date_prev_week.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    month_lw = int(date_prev_week.strftime("%m"))
    year_lw = int(date_prev_week.strftime("%Y"))

    # get last day of previous month
    last_day_previous_month = calendar.monthrange(year_lw, month_lw)[1]
    date_last_prev = date_prev_week.replace(day=last_day_previous_month)
    date_last_day_previous_month_num = date_last_prev.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    # use babel to get the long readable formated date
    spanish_text_date_current = format_date(date_last, format='long', locale='es')
    spanish_text_date_previous = format_date(date_last_prev, format='long', locale='es')

    # choose date to display depending on current date
    day_today = int(today.strftime("%d"))
    if day_today > 3:
        return date_last_day_current_month_num, spanish_text_date_current
    else:
        return date_last_day_previous_month_num, spanish_text_date_previous


date_last_day_num, spanish_text_date = es_date()
date_last_day_num, catalan_text_date = cat_date()
```

A **context_processors.py** in charge of passing the variables to the templates::

```
from .utils import date_last_day_num, catalan_text_date, spanish_text_date

def last_day(request):
    context = {
        'date_last_day_num': date_last_day_num,
        'catalan_text_date': catalan_text_date,
        'spanish_text_date': spanish_text_date,
    }
    return context
```

Then I just call the variable from the template:

```
{{ spanish_text_date }}
```

**EDIT:**

Nginx --> my-site_project file:

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
    server_name 123.123.123.12 my-site.com www.my-site.com;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    256;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_vary          on;

    gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/ld+json
    application/manifest+json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.geo+json
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/bmp
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/cache-manifest
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/vcard
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    text/vtt
    text/x-component
    text/x-cross-domain-policy;

    expires $expires;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/my-site/src;
    }
 location /media/ {
        root /home/user/my-site/src;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.my-site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = my-site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name my-site.com www.my-site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Sorry for such a long post, but I think the information could be relevant. I appreciate your time and help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your **utils.py** gets imported the first time, the variables `catalan_text_date`... are calculated, since they are at the top level of your file. This happens when you start gunicorn because it imports **context_processors.py** then which in turn imports these variables. From then on it never needs to call `cat_date()` again because `catalan_text_date` is in memory and global.

You should call the functions `es_date()` and `cat_date()` in your context processor instead of using the calculated variables. Just import `es_date` and `cat_date` and then use these in your `last_day` function.

Comment: Although your answer makes total sense to me. After moving the function execution I have the same result, perfect locally and not updating on server. I tried to browse using a Chrome incognito window, to double check if the page was being cached, same result. I add the nginx project file perhaps, the reason is there